# Flask - enviando retorno do form para outra função

Tags: python, rest, request, flask

Abaixo está o meu default.py onde defino os end-point;
O que estou tentando fazer é pegar a informação do FORM que está em **"/"** enviar para o **return_request()** e apesentar o resultado da Request em **"/output"**

```
def return_request(endPoint):
 headerInfo = {
    'content-type': 'application/ld+json',
    'X-API-KEY': '3feff58c-5302-49da-803e-25eb0a34dce5'
 }

 url = "..../"

 res = requests.get(url + '%s' % (endPoint), headers=headerInfo)

 return res


@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
 form = ReqForm()
 if form.validate_on_submit():

    form.reset()
 else:
    pass

 return render_template('index.html', req=form)


@app.route("/output", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def output():

return render_template('output.html')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a solução fazendo assim:

```
@app.route("/index", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def load():
form = ReqForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
    output = request.form['field']
    print(output)
    endPoint = output
    headerInfo = {
        'content-type': 'application/ld+json',
        'X-API-KEY': '3feff58c-5302-49da-803e-25eb0a34dce5'
    }

    url = "..."

    res = requests.get(url + '%s' % (endPoint), headers=headerInfo)
    print(res.status_code)
    if res.status_code == 200:
        texto = json.loads(res.content)
        texto = texto.get("hydra:member")

else:
    pass

return render_template('load.html', form=form, texto=texto)
```

Combinei tudo dentro de uma unica função... ainda não é o formato que eu queria, porem está funcionando...

Answer (score 0):

Falta um espaço no ultimo `return`, isto:

```
@app.route("/output", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def output():

return render_template('output.html')
```

Deveria ser:

```
@app.route("/output", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def output():
  return render_template('output.html')
```

Em **Python** indentação é "tudo", eu pessoalmente prefiro 3 ou 4 espaços, assim:

```
def return_request(endPoint):
    headerInfo = {
        'content-type': 'application/ld+json',
        'X-API-KEY': '3feff58c-5302-49da-803e-25eb0a34dce5'
    }

    url = "http://beta.pdvmundo.solutions/api/"

    res = requests.get(url + '%s' % (endPoint), headers=headerInfo)

    return res


@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    form = ReqForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        form.reset()
    else:
        pass

    return render_template('index.html', req=form)


@app.route("/output", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def output():
    return render_template('output.html')
```

Comment: Sim, no meu código está indentado de boa. é que estou me acostumando a usar o StackOverflow

Comment: @CristopherGollmann entendo, então qual o erro ocorre exatamente? /output esta exibindo vazio ou 404?

Comment: então é que assim, o que eu quero saber é como eu mando o imput do FORM para a a função return_request() e depois como eu pego o retorno dessa função e mostro no /output